# How to mock only a particular route in axios using jest but still keeping the other routes functional as normal

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I am calling /route1 using axios (as shown below). But route1 internally it calls /route2.
I want to mock route2 response but still keeping the route1 working as normal.

```
const axios = require('axios');
jest.mock('axios');

it(`gets data`, async () => {
  axios.post.mockImplementation(url => {
    if(url.includes(`/route2`))
    {
      return Promise.resolve({data : {message: 'ok'}});
    }
  });
  const res = await axios.post(`/route1`, dataQuery);
  expect(res).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This code is also mocking /route1 and i get undefined response.
How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally unacceptable to perform real network requests in Jest tests, it doesn't guarantee that the same request would work in real application, provides very little value and a considerable inconvenience. This especially applies to unit tests that should be fast and stable. If tests require real network activity, they can be reserved for browser E2E and integration tests.

So it's normal to have entirely mocked Axios.

Any way, once `axios` package has been mocked, real implementation needs to be explicitly accessed to do this:

```
  axios.post.mockImplementation(url => {
   if(url.includes(`/route2`)) {
      return Promise.resolve({data : {message: 'ok'}});
    } else {
      const unmockedAxios = jest.requireActual('axios');
      return unmockedAxios.post(url);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the other functions in the axios module is also getting undefined. Like axios.defaults is undefined. Not sure how to mock only a particular function while keeping all the remaining methods unmocked.

Comment: Then the problem differs from what you stated in the question. You need to mock a separate method, `jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockImplementation(...same as above...)`. Do not mock the entire module.

Comment: Thank you. Glad I found this.